# How can I center a Sweave verbatim chunk?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, verbatim, r, sweave

I have a very simple sweave chunk with two lines, like this:

```
<<results=verbatim>>==
quantile(foo$bar)
@
```

How can I center this element? I've tried embracing the chunk with `\begin{center}` to no avail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A verbatim environment by default has the width equal to the text width.  Thus you cannot center it:  the trailing whitespace is included in the line.

Fortunately, `Sweave.sty` uses `fancyvrb` package internally.  `Sweave` defines three environments, for the input, output and code, using `fancyvrb` in the following way:

```
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Sinput}{Verbatim}{fontshape=sl}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Soutput}{Verbatim}{}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Scode}{Verbatim}{fontshape=sl}
```

Now `fancyvrb` has several environments.  One which is helpful in your case is `BVerbatim`:  the text is put into a box with the width by default equal to the width of the longest line of the text.  The resulting box can be centered.

Thus the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Sweave}
\pagestyle{empty}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Soutput}{BVerbatim}{}
\begin{document}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.1pt} % To show centering
\begin{center}
<<>>==
2+3
@
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

We redefined `Soutput` as `BVerbatim`, and the output is now centered:

[image]

Note that only the output is centered in this example.  To center input, redefine `Sinput` as well.

Comment: Really nice answer!

Comment: @Boris, I've just noticed one problem with that configuration. At the end of the file, I insert another verbatim chunk which is just a print of part of a data frame. However, `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Soutput}{Verbatim}{}` prevents page breaking, so that last chunk will never fit the page (it has 129 rows and 3 cols). How can I prevent this?

Comment: Well, `BVerbatim` is a box, so it is not splittable.  Redefine the `Soutput` back to `Verbatim` just before this large chunk.